# How to cancel all JAVA running methods (including locked ones) from JSF call from GUI?

Tags: java, jsf, user-interface

I'm trying to discuss a way of getting all my JAVA methods to break their execution and finish right away (from what they are doing of course) when the user of the GUI click on a 'cancel' button in a GUI made in JSF script (after making the calls to an specific calculations method of course).

It has to cancel ALL JAVA methods, including locked methods that are waiting for other threads to finish [waiting their return from callable with the use of future.get()]

Is there a easy way of doing that?

Regards,

Comment: GUI made in JSF executes in a browser, and java methods on a server, right?

Comment: I still don't understand if you have a Web or a Desktop Application.

Comment: Alexei Kaigorodov yes, i do have a GUI made in JSF that executes in a web-browser, and java methods on an app-server being called. The final GUI is definatly a browser. Is there a way of cancelling all java methods being run (or locked, waiting) when the user click on a button (cancel button)?